# Material to record though so camera isn't visible?

Tags: video

I am building an Arduino (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) device that will record video based on a motion sensors, as well as other data in the environment. The thing is, I need to record from within a box to the outside, but the camera should not be visible. Any ideas or advice on how and what to use?

Comment: If the camera can see you, you can see the camera (except possibly through a half-silvered mirror). All you can do is disguise it, for example "teddy-bear cams". How big is the lens opening? What are the surroundings? How is the scene lit? More details will help.

Answer (score 1):

If quality of video is not so important to you, then you can use effect, which is used on public transport windows:
[image]

It is when you use lot of dots on the glass. From the outside it looks like semitransparent image. But from inside it will look like that:
[image]

With correct focus dots will be less visible on video.

And second option is to use half-silvered mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Traffic cameras and security cameras shoot through a dark glass, so you could use something like that.

I'm sure you've seen those black domes in stores - it's called a Pan/Tilt/Zoom (PTZ) dome.  You might look in the area of security camera accessories.